# PHP populated dropdown, onchange populate different dropdown based on value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, dropdown

Hi so the here is my question,

I have a Database containing Categories and Subcategories.
I have two dropdown boxes (select). I want them both to be populated by using PHP/MYSQL.

My Categories have been generated:

```
<select name="prod_cat">
    <?php
        include("php/dbconnect.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo '<option value="'. $row["cat_name"] .'">'. $row["cat_name"] .'</option>';
            }
        }
        else{echo "No categories were found!";}
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</select>
```

[image: browser preview of dropdown boxes]

I want the subcategories to load when the category has changed.
My SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT subcat_name FROM subcategories WHERE cat_name = '$prod_cat'
```

I need to get the value from the categories dropdown and store it as a variable.
In the past I have done something similar in javascript:

```
var subcat=document.forms["form"]['subcat'].value;
```

and then changed the value of another dropdown by calling an onChange(); function like:

```
document.getElementById('subcat').innerHTML='<option value=""></option>';
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction! Should I be looking into AJAX, JavaScript or can it all be done with PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: u should use jquery for this in combination with AJAX . what u want to get cant be done in php alone because php is Server side and JavaScript and Dropdown selection is clientside. however u can use jquery to do an "onChange" function for the Dropdown and then call a PHP script over AJAX to insert stuff. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add an id on category select box , like this -

```
<select name="prod_cat" id="prod_cat">
    <?php
        include("php/dbconnect.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo '<option value="'. $row["cat_name"] .'">'. $row["cat_name"] .'</option>';
            }
        }
        else{echo "No categories were found!";}
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</select>
```

for subcategory -

```
<select id='sub_cat' name='sub_cat'></select>
```

write your script something like this -

```
<script>
$("#prod_cat").change(function(){
    //get category value
    var cat_val = $("#prod_cat").val();
    // put your ajax url here to fetch subcategory
    var url             =   'www.example/fetch_subcategory.php';
    // call subcategory ajax here 
    $.ajax({
                   type:"POST",
                   url:url,
                   data:{
                       cat_val : cat_val
                   },

                   success:function(data)
                    {
                        $("#sub_cat").html(data);
                    }
                });
});
</script>
```

add code in ajax calling page -'www.example/fetch_subcategory.php'

```
<?php
$prod_cat = $_POST['cat_val'];

$sql = "SELECT subcat_name FROM subcategories WHERE cat_name = '$prod_cat'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$msg ='';
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
           $msg =.'<option value="'. $row["sub_cat_name"] .'">'. $row["sub_cat_name"] .'</option>';
            }
        }
        else{$msg .="No categories were found!";}
        echo $msg;
        mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
```

Do something like this, and hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying your method now, not got it working yet and i'm trying to figure out why. Do I need to link an AJAX library?